# use constexpr to determine size of array pointer

Tags: c++, constexpr, auto, decltype

I am using constexpr to declare size of std::array.

```
constexprt auto sizearr = 99;
```

Based on compile time type deduction on sizearr I want to find type of index used to iterate array

```
char offset; //Class member
```

when sizearr changed to

```
constexprt auto sizearr = 65000;
```

I want offset to auto declared as type of int instead of changing manually to int.

I am assuming there must be way to mix auto, decltype and constexpr to do this.

Comment: Isn't the type of the index for `std::array` always `std::size_t`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 0):

Use log2(arraysize)/8 (cast to int) as a non-type template parameter N.

The template is a struct template that defines a type that you need.

Partial specialize based upon value of N.